# Laptop does not wake from sleep

Tags: 20.04, suspend, lenovo, laptop

I have a new Lenovo Thinkbook (without Nvidia graphics) with a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install. Everything seems to work, except for suspend, which is a big issue.

First, I discovered that it was not suspending in a way that preserved battery, so I enabled deep sleep, rather than s2idle sleep, by adding mem_sleep_default=sleep to the GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line of the grub configuration.

Next, I realised that the swapfile was not big enough to suspend to RAM. I followed this guide: https://rephlex.de/blog/2019/12/27/how-to-hibernate-and-resume-from-swap-file-in-ubuntu-20-04-using-full-disk-encryption/ -- which means I made my swap file the same size as my RAM (`sudo swapoff /swapfile`, `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | grep -oh '[0-9]*') count=1024 conv=notrunc`, `sudo mkswap /swapfile`, `sudo swapon /swapfile`), and configured uswsusp and grub to use the swap file.

But now, when I suspend, either using the top bar button, or running sudo pm-suspend, or writing "mem" to /sys/power/state, it won't resume. When I hit a key to resume the laptop, the keyboard lights up, and the fans start, but the display does not turn on. Input does not appear to be working, as the fn/caps lock keys, which have light indicators, are not responding. I also tried running some music before sleeping, and it did not resume when I tried waking.

I have to reboot using the power button, but even that seems to not work well. I press and hold the power button until the laptop seems off, and then I try to start it, and the same behaviour resumes. I might have to repeat this five or more times before the laptop seems to power off as expected, enabling me to reboot it.

What do I do now?

N.B. The same resume behaviour happened before I expanded the swap file size, which I had hoped would fix the problem.

N.B. Hibernating to disk, as well as sleeping with s2idle2, both work fine.

Comment: Don't "expand" the swap file. Swap files must be contiguous. `swapoff`, delete old swapfile, create new, bigger swapfile, `swapon`. Read `man mkswap swapon pm-is-supported`.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced the same issue a few weeks back when I installed Ubuntu on my new laptop. Here is a fix (which involves partially disabling the suspend thing)

I've found a workaround

1. Set "blank screen" to "never" in settings>power
2. Set "automatic suspend" to "off" in settings>power
3. Set "power button action" to anything other than "suspend" in settings>power
4. The most important :
   Open logind.conf file in
   etc/systemd using gedit

   "sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf"

Then uncomment (remove the #) the line containing "HandleLidSwitch" and set its value to "lock"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this does not work. (And I'm unsure why it would.) I followed your instructions, and then did `echo deep>/sys/power/mem_sleep` followed by `echo mem>/sys/power/state`, and suspend (mis)behaved just like before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still having this problem, but here is what happened to me on my AMD Thinkbook:

- Originally changed to use S3 instead of Modern-Standby
- A subsequent kernel update broke that, so rolled back to an earlier kernel
- Later, updated the BIOS and it broke suspend again (Hangs on resume).

**Fix**: Go into the hidden BIOS and changing S3 back to Modern-Standby.
**Instructions**:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/n9xrgp/comment/h1wku6m/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

**Updated**:  After testing found battery use of Modern-Standby is unacceptable: 8% per hour.

So reenabled S3, and added to grub boot "amd_iommu=off" and now suspend no longer crashes.  Yay: only took 15 hours of hacking around to get it to work.

Comment: Update: Tested with Modern-Standby and it looks to use about 8% battery per hour.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried almost everything and finally what worked on my lenovo Ideapad 5 was changing HandleLidSwitch to lock, but don't remove the #.

Comment: If the line starts with # that is a comment so any change to that line does nothing it will not get processed. So that in itself did not fix it.